# How to add multiple variables to one jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, variables

This is a beginner question, sorry for that:

I`ve got this code:

```
iosSunset.css('opacity', '1');
mbaSunset.css('opacity', '1');
mbaGreece.css('opacity', '0');
iosGreece.css('opacity', '0');
```

Is there a way like this:

```
$(iosSunset, mbaSunset).css('opacity', '1');
$(iosSunset, mbaSunset).css('opacity', '0');
```

But this code doesn`t work :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to join jQuery objects

```
iosSunset.add(mbaSunset).css('opacity', '1');
iosSunset.add(mbaSunset).add(mbaGreece).css('opacity', '1');
```